# Scrapy spider difference between Crawled pages and Scraped items

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

Im writing a Scrapy CrawlSpider that reads a list of ADs on first page, takes some info like thumbs of the listings and AD urls, then yields a request to each of this AD urls to take their details.

It was working and paginating apparently well on test enviroment, but today trying to make a complete run I realized that in log:

Crawled **3852** pages (at 228 pages/min), scraped **256** items (at 15 items/min)

I'm not understanding the reason of this big difference between Crawled pages and Scraped items. Anybody can help me to realize where that items are getting lost?

My spider code:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["myspider.com", "myspider.co"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.myspider.com/offers/myCity/typeOfAd/?search=fast",
    ]

    #Pagination
    rules = (
        Rule (
            SgmlLinkExtractor()
           , callback='parse_start_url', follow= True),
    )

    #1st page
    def parse_start_url(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        next_page = hxs.select("//a[@class='pagNext']/@href").extract()
        offers = hxs.select("//div[@class='hlist']")

        for offer in offers:
            myItem = myItem()

            myItem['url'] = offer.select('.//span[@class="location"]/a/@href').extract()[0]
            myItem['thumb'] = oferta.select('.//div[@class="itemFoto"]/div/a/img/@src').extract()[0]

            request = Request(myItem['url'], callback = self.second_page)
            request.meta['myItem'] = myItem

            yield request

        if next_page:
            yield Request(next_page[0], callback=self.parse_start_url)


    def second_page(self,response):
        myItem = response.meta['myItem']

        loader = myItemLoader(item=myItem, response=response)

        loader.add_xpath('address', '//span[@itemprop="streetAddress"]/text()') 

        return loader.load_item()
```

Comment: Pages can be crawled but some things may not be scraped, maybe nothing matched your criteria on the page you crawled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you go to your first `start_urls` (actually you only have one) and on this page there is only one anchor link (`<a>`).  So your spider crawls the `href` url in this link and you get control in your callback, `parse_start_url`.  And inside of this page you have 5000 div's with an `hlist` class.  And let's suppose all 5000 of these subsequent URLs were returned 404, not found.

In this case  you would have:

- Pages crawled: 5001
- Items scraped: 0

Let's take another example: on your start url page you have 5000 anchors, but none (as in zero) of those pages have any divs with a class parameter of `hlist`.

In this case  you would have:

- Pages crawled: 5001
- Items scraped: 0

Your answer lies in the DEBUG log output.

Comment: Actually, each page of my start_urls response returns 26 valid urls. They all leads me to a basic template, and items are suposed to be scraped even if all data in subpages are empty.

As my DEBUG do not show me any error, I`m afraid that this (26) requests yielded in the offers loop can be in someway blocked/lost in the moment of next_page request, do you think this structure is in the correct way?

Comment: Yeah, the structure looks ok, but its hard to guess what is happening without either the log output or the actual urls.