# what's the scrapy log mean

Tags: python, scrapy

for example

```
2016-01-07 11:37:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 61 pages (at 61 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-07 11:38:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 171 pages (at 110 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-07 11:39:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 299 pages (at 128 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-07 11:40:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 394 pages (at 95 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-07 11:41:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 487 pages (at 93 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-07 11:42:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 554 pages (at 67 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-07 11:43:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 616 pages (at 62 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-01-07 11:44:19 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 743 pages (at 127 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

1. what do the word"Crawled","scraped"mean?
2. when the scrapy will print log,such as"Crawled 743 pages (at 127 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)",at that time which function is called?

Comment: items are scraped when your function `yield` items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy spider difference between Crawled pages and Scraped items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957853/scrapy-spider-difference-between-crawled-pages-and-scraped-items)

Answer (score -1):

1. A crawled page is a page that one of your spiders have requested. It is supposed to parse it as well, depending of how you programmed it. An item scraped is a set of data extracted from that parsing. Both are explained in the scrapy tutorial: [items](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/intro/tutorial.html#defining-our-item) and [spiders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/intro/tutorial.html#our-first-spider)
2. I'm not exactly sure, but if i remember correctly this is printed when a spider finish its job.